# Dart (transitive) Dependency overrides

Tags: flutter, dart, pubspec

I have the following package dependency chain:

> myapp uses packageA uses packageB

A and B are 3rd party, and myapp has a transitive dependency on B.

After upgrading to more recent flutter SDK, I find that B no longer compiles. The fix is a one-liner to one the files in B.

I can obviously modify the file in pubcache locally, but this is obviously not a good idea.

So what is best practice for dealing with this scenario?

Should I fork B, clone it, and modify it locally. And if I do that, how do I force myapp, and more importantly packageA, to use my fixed-up packageB?

For example, if I use dependency_overrides in myapp's pubspec.yaml, will package A honor that? I'm guessing not?

Many thanks